# How to move items between two ListViews with change listener JavaFX

Tags: java, listview, javafx, listener

I have two `ListView`s, `allStudentsList` has items already populated within it, `currentStudentList` has none. My aim for when the user selects an item in `allStudentList` is for that item be moved into `currentStudentList`. I have done this by placing a listener on the selection model of the `allStudentList`.

I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` and I am not sure why this is occurring. From testing, it seems that this problem is isolated to the last 4 lines of this method yet I am not sure why.

```
allStudentsList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()
        .addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (allStudentsList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {

                ArrayList<String> tempCurrent = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String s : currentStudentList.getItems()) {
                    tempCurrent.add(s);
                }

                ArrayList<String> tempAll = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String s : allStudentsList.getItems()) {
                    tempAll.add(s);
                }

                tempAll.remove(newValue);
                tempCurrent.add(newValue);

                // clears current studentlist and adds the new list
                if (currentStudentList.getItems().size() != 0) {
                    currentStudentList.getItems().clear();
                }
                currentStudentList.getItems().addAll(tempCurrent);

                // clears the allStudentList and adds the new list
                if (allStudentsList.getItems().size() != 0) {
                    allStudentsList.getItems().clear();
                }
                allStudentsList.getItems().addAll(tempAll);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: allStudents.getItems().clear();

Comment: allStudentsList.getItems().addAll(tempAll);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a quick fix you can wrap the code parts that modify the item lists into a `Platform.runLater(...)` block:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    // clears current studentlist and adds the new list
    if (currentStudentList.getItems().size() != 0) 
        currentStudentList.getItems().clear();

    currentStudentList.getItems().addAll(tempCurrent);
});

Platform.runLater(() -> {
    // clears the allStudentList and adds the new list
    if (allStudentsList.getItems().size() != 0) 
        allStudentsList.getItems().clear();

    allStudentsList.getItems().addAll(tempAll);
});
```

The problem is that you cannot change the selection while a selection change is being processed. As you remove all elements with `allStudentsList.getItems().clear();`, the selection will change (the selected index will be `-1`), the mentioned condition will met. This is what the usage of the `Platform.runLater(...)` block will prevent by "postponing" the modification.

But your whole handler could be exchanged with

```
allStudentsList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue != null) {

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            allStudentsList.getSelectionModel().select(-1);
            currentStudentList.getItems().add(newValue);
            allStudentsList.getItems().remove(newValue);
        });
    }
});
```

It sets the selected index to `-1`: nothing is selected in the `ListView` to avoid changing to a different item when removing the current one (this was done implicitly in your version by clearing the list), then it adds the currently selected element to the s"elected list", then it removes the current element from the "all item list". All of these actions are wrapped in the mentioned `Platform.runLater(...)` block.